# Problems about python logging.config.dictConfig

Tags: python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I study logging module recording some message recently. I want to pass a self-defined log path to the dict configuration. For the sake of calling it conveniently, I encapsulate some code into a class.

Now my problem is when I call it, which does't work. The effect which I expect is logging the message both into the console and /tmp/xxxx.log.

Here is the code.(Sorry about my poor English)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import logging
from logging.config import dictConfig

debug = True

class RequireDebugTrue(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return debug 

logconf_dict = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,

    'formatters': {
        'debug_fmt': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(threadName)s:%(thread)d][%(name)s:'
                '%(levelname)s][%(module)s:%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d)]:%(message)s'
        },
        'prod_fmt': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s][%(name)s:%(levelname)s]'
                '[%(module)s:%(funcName)s(%(lineno)d)]:%(message)s'
        }
    },

    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': RequireDebugTrue,
        }
    },

    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'debug_fmt',
            'filters': ['require_debug_true']
        },
        'localfile': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'prod_fmt',
            'filename': '/tmp/running.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 5,
            'backupCount': 5,
            'encoding': 'utf8'
        },
    },

    'loggers': {
        'debug_mode': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'localfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'prod_mode': {
            'handlers': ['localfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}

class Get_Logger(object):

    def __init__(self, logfile, log_handler):
        self.log_handler = log_handler
        self.logfile = logfile

    def get_logger(self):
        logconf_dict["handlers"]["localfile"]["filename"] = self.logfile
        dictConfig(logconf_dict)
        logger = logging.getLogger(self.log_handler)
        return logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = "/tmp/xxxx.log"
    logger_obj = Get_Logger("debug_mode", logfile)
    logger = logger_obj.get_logger()
    logger.debug("This is one test.")
```

If I disable the encapsulated code, and call the code inside directly, which works fine. Good codes like this:

```
logconf_dict["handlers"]["localfile"]["filename"] = "/tmp/xxxx.log"
dictConfig(logconf_dict)
logger = logging.getLogger("debug_mode")
logger.debug("This is one test.")
```

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Problem solved.
Sorry to interrupt. I made a huge mistake about calling code, argument error caused wrong results. Silly of me.

Comment: How to close this question?

Comment: You can post your solution as the answer.

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Well, the error is in the definition of init function.
Wrong code line: def __init__(self, logfile, log_handler):
Right code line: def __init__(self, log_handler, logfile):
Just change the position between logfile and log_handler.

Comment: Please find a tutorial how to post an answer on SO here: https://www.wikihow.com/Answer-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is just changing the position between logfile and log_handler.
Wrong code line: *def **init**(self, logfile, log_handler):*
Right code line: *def **init**(self, log_handler, logfile):*
Silly of me. Sorry to interrupt.